# How to filter Record values of files in hadoop mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am working with a program in MapReduce. I have two files and I want to delete some information from file1 that exists in file2. Every line has an ID as its key and some numbers (separated by comma) as its value.

```
file1:
1    1,2,10
2    2,7,8,5
3    3,9,12
```

and

```
file2:
1    1
2    2,5
3    3,9
```

I want output like this:

```
output:    
1    2,10
2    7,8
3    12
```

I want to delete values of file1 that have the same key in file2. One way to do this is have the two files as input files and in the map step produce: `(ID, line)`. Then in the reduce step I filter the values. But, my files are very very large and therefore I can't do it this way.

Or, would it be efficient if file1 was the input file and in the map I open file2 and seek to that line and then compare the value? But as I have a million keys and for every key I must open file1, I think it will have excessive I/O.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can make both file1 and file2 inputs of your mapper. In the mapper you'd add the source (file1 or file2) to the records. Then use secondary sort to make sure records from file2 always come first. So, the combined input for your reducer would look like that:

```
1    file2,1
1    file1,1,2,10
2    file2,2,5
2    file1,2,7,8,5
3    file2,3,9
3    file1,3,9,12
```

You can take the design of the reducer from here.

Comment: Thanks but in this way i have a lot of key value pair and map output becomes very large.

Comment: This is called BigData for reason ;-) I was actually thinking that the values would be comma-separated lists. So you'd get at most 2 values per key.